# Scoring system not working AS3

Tags: actionscript-3

It's me again, I've finally made the math generator to work and see if the answer is correct or incorrect, hooray! But, this is programming, and another error appeared, darn-it.

So I added a scoring system and at the first correct answer it gives me 1 point but at the second correct answer it doesn't give me another point, it stays at 1 point. Also, is there a way to block the `verificar` button until the `startButton` button is pressed? (so people that try my math generator don't cheat!) Thank you very much for your help!

```as3
import flash.utils.Timer;
import flash.events.MouseEvent;
import flash.events.TimerEvent;

stop()

var reloj:Timer = new Timer(1000,60);
startButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, startTimer);
reloj.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER, moveHand);
reloj.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, endTimer);

function startTimer(e:MouseEvent):void {
    reloj.start();
    startButton.visible = false;
}

function moveHand(e:TimerEvent):void {
    segundero.rotation = segundero.rotation + 6
}

function endTimer(e:TimerEvent):void {
    trace("Se agotó el tiempo");
    gotoAndPlay (1, "1");
}

nuevo.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, generarPregunta);

function generarPregunta(MouseEvent):void {
    var random1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
    var random2:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25)
    var array:Array = new Array ("+","-","*","/")
    var randomIndex:int = Math.floor (Math.random()*4)
    SimbMat.text = array [ randomIndex ]
    numI.text = random1 + ""
    numD.text = random2 + ""
}

verificar.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, verificarRespuesta);

function verificarRespuesta(MouseEvent):void {
    var puntaje:int = 0
    if (String(SimbMat.text) == "+") {
        if (Number(numI.text) + Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text)) {
                trace("correcto")
                puntaje++;
                updateScore();
                generarPregunta(MouseEvent);
        } else {
            trace("incorrecto")
        }
    } else if (String(SimbMat.text) == "-") {
        if (Number(numI.text) - Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text)) {
            trace("correcto")
            puntaje++;
            updateScore();
            generarPregunta(MouseEvent);
        }
        else {
            trace("incorrecto")
        }
    } else if (String(SimbMat.text) == "*") {
        if (Number(numI.text) * Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text)) {
            trace("correcto")
            puntaje++;
            updateScore();
            generarPregunta(MouseEvent);
        } else {
            trace("incorrecto")
        }
    } else if (String(SimbMat.text) == "/") {
        if (Number(numI.text) / Number(numD.text) == Number(imput.text)) {
            trace("correcto")
            puntaje++;
            updateScore();
            generarPregunta(MouseEvent);
        } else {
            trace("incorrecto")
        }
    }

    function updateScore() :void {
        score.text = "Puntaje: " + puntaje;
    }

}
```

Comment: A lot of the lines in your code are missing an ending semicolon (`;`). Also, your opening brackets (`{`) and closing brackets (`}`) don't match up.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but at the second correct answer it doesn't give me another point, it
>   stays at 1 point.

Now, the puntaje has reseted to zero everytime.
You should define puntaje(total point?) at outside of verificarRespuesta function.

```
var puntaje:int;

function startTimer(e:MouseEvent):void {
    reloj.start();

    // reset to zero here?
    puntaje = 0;

    startButton.visible = false;
}
```

> Also, is there a way to block the verificar button until the
>   startButton button is pressed?

Set `enable=false` or `visible=false` first and set it true at inside of startTimer or generarPregunta function. Like this.

```
// set enable=false first
verificar.enable = false;

function generarPregunta(MouseEvent):void {
    var random1:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
    var random2:Number = Math.floor(Math.random()*25);
    var array:Array = new Array ("+","-","*","/");
    var randomIndex:int = Math.floor (Math.random()*4);
    SimbMat.text = array [ randomIndex ];
    numI.text = random1 + "";
    numD.text = random2 + "";

    verificar.enable = true;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, you solved my problem now my proyect is finished!! I can't thank you enough! (seriously, i can't give points, only accept your answer :( but still, thank you.)